# Jquery AutoComplete no list output

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

When i use the autocomplete Jquery below on a *element loaded with the initial page (#tsearch)* it performs as expected. When I try to attach the autocomplete Jquery to a *element on a form that was dynamically displayed (#crec)* using .load() i get a strange behavior. The CSS classes and inline attributes that autocomplete adds and manipulates on the element are present in the element and react to "typing" in the form field (as shown by firebug.console), but no list of choices displays. It is as if a part of the Jquery functionality attaches but other parts fail, there are no errors thrown to console and the only change to the Jquery code is the target element, both of which are just text input boxes.

**Jquery (Targeting non dynamic element)**

```
$(document).on("click","#tsearch", function() {
    var customers = [
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tickets`";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $a = "\"$row[ticketnum] : $row[cfirstname] $row[clastname]\"," . $a;
        }
        $a = rtrim($a, ",");
        echo $a;
         ?>
    ];

        $( "#tsearch" ).autocomplete({source: customers});
        });
```

**Jquery when viewed in source view**

```
$(document).on("click","#tsearch", function() {
var customers = [
"08311502 : Bill Stewart","08311500 : John Williams"];
$( "#tsearch" ).autocomplete({source: customers});
});
```

**Two quick notes:** All Jquery is being loaded on the source page, no jquery is in the dynamically loaded page. Also, I have not yet tried placing the above Jquery in the callback of the .load() that displays the dynamic form HOWEVER, since all of the Jquery classes and actions appear to be attaching properly without in being in the callback, i'm not sure why or if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a matter of events. If the element in question is initially loaded jQuery should establish all the hooks necessary to do it's autocomplete thing. If the element you want to autocomplete is dynamically loaded into the page then the DOM should know everything about the element allowing jQuery to do CSS manipulation and "react" to it. So I imagine when you put the the code in question inside the .load function you're allowing jQuery to establish the specialized hooks it creates for that element that it needs to function correctly.

If you debug the events that occur you may be able to recognize what's not being called compared to not having that code inside the .load callback.

Comment: I'll try to do some A B split testing when time permits, im not sure how to event break or console.log events that are internal to Jquery which i assume all of autocomplete functionality is. But I'll look into what i can debug.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the "Jquery" in question inside the scope of the callback of the .load() resolved the functionality. Having stated that, the behavior is not what was expected and I cannot say I understand why this corrects the problem. So, until someone advises a better explanation this is what worked for now.